# Using the libzip with Qt 5 on OSX mountain lion

Tags: c++, qt, zip, unzip

I'm trying to make a simple program for training using the libzip to list the content of an archive (goal for now :). I'm using the libzip sources.

.pro file:

```
QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    myZip.cpp \

INCLUDEPATH = /path/to/libzip

HEADERS += \
    myZip.h \
```

MCZip.h

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "zip.h"

class myZip : public QDialog
{
public:
    myZip(const char* filePath);

private:
    QTextEdit *m_fileListView;
    QString m_fileList;

    QPushButton *m_closeButton;

};
```

myZip.cpp

```
#include "my.h"

myZip::myZip(const char* filePath)
{
    setFixedSize(400, 400);

    m_fileListView = new QTextEdit;
    m_closeButton = new QPushButton("Close");

    int err = 0;
    struct zip *f_zip=NULL;

    f_zip = zip_open(filePath, ZIP_CHECKCONS, &err);

    if(err != ZIP_ER_OK)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Cannot open the file!");
        return;
    }

    if(f_zip == NULL)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "File not found");
        return;
    }

    int fileCount = zip_get_num_files(f_zip);
    if (fileCount ==-1)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "The archive seems corrupted");
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << QString("There are %1 files in the archive").arg(fileCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
    {
        m_fileList += QString(QString::fromLocal8Bit(zip_get_name(f_zip, i, ZIP_FL_UNCHANGED)) + "\n");
    }

    zip_close(f_zip);
    f_zip = NULL;

    m_fileListView->setText(m_fileList);

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(m_fileListView);
    layout->addWidget(m_closeButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    QObject::connect(m_closeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MCCover.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a file", QString(),
                                             "Zip archive (*.zip)"); 

    QByteArray byteArray = filePath.toUtf8();
    const char* cFilePath = byteArray.constData();

    myZip *fileList = new myZip(cFilePath);
    fileList.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

The problem is when I compile, I get the following message:

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld return exit status
```

And when I look to the output I have

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
        "_zip_close", referenced from:
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
        "_zip_get_name", referenced from:
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
        "_zip_get_num_files", referenced from:
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
        "_zip_open", referenced from:
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
              myZip::myZip(char const*)in myZip.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea on how I could solve the problem? I could not find any solution...

For info I followed this tutoriel on how using the libzip [in French]:
    http://slash.developpez.com/tutoriels/c/utilisation-libzip/

Configuration: Qt 5.0.0 on OSX Mountain Lion with clang_64 compiler (default)

Thanks

WDeadpool

PS: When adapting the code, it does not work either using qt 4.8.1 with gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Build libzip as a static library and then link your project to this static library
- Add the source files of libzip to your project

Answer (score 0):

Example (On Linux)
In `.pro` file:

```
HEADERS +=  /usr/include/zip.h

LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lzip

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include headers
```

Function that zip file:

```
int PutFileIntoZip(const QString &filePath)
{
    QFile regFile(filePath);
    Q_ASSERT(regFile.exists());
    const bool canOpenRegFile=regFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if(canOpenRegFile)
    {
        QString fileNameExpansion=filePath.section(QDir::separator(),-1,-1);
        const QStringRef fileName(&fileNameExpansion, 0, fileNameExpansion.length()-4);//22222.bin -> 22222
        int errorFlagCreateZip = 0;
        const QString zipPath=QDir::homePath()+QDir::separator()+fileName + "2.zip";
        zip*const  zipHandle = zip_open(zipPath.toLatin1().constData(), ZIP_CREATE, &errorFlagCreateZip);
        if (ZIP_ER_OK==errorFlagCreateZip)
        {
            FILE* const fileC = fdopen(regFile.handle(), "r");
            zip_source* const  source = zip_source_filep(zipHandle, fileC, 0, regFile.size());
            if (source!=nullptr)
            {
                const zip_int64_t result = zip_file_add(zipHandle, fileNameExpansion.toLatin1().constData(), source, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE);
                if (result>=0)
                {
                    zip_set_file_compression(zipHandle, result, ZIP_CM_DEFLATE64, 0);
                    qDebug()<< "Done";
                }
                else
                {
                    zip_source_free(source);
                }
            }
            int result = zip_close(zipHandle);
            fclose(fileC);
            regFile.close();
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            zip_error_t error;
            zip_error_init_with_code(&error, errorFlagCreateZip);
            const int zipCreationErrorCode = zip_error_code_zip(&error);
            regFile.close();
            return zipCreationErrorCode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<< regFile.errorString();
        return -1;
    }
}
```